# Primefaces p:remoteCommand update clears google maps listener

Tags: google-maps, jsf, google-maps-api-3, primefaces

I draw some polygons on my map on the server side every time the zoom change. This works fine!

My problem is that the call to "update" on the p:remoteCommand is destroying my listener "zoom_changed" after the first execution. If I remove that "update" the 'zoom_change' listener works fine, but the map is not updated and the polygons never appears (only if I refresh the page).

What I need to do to make this two things working together?

I'm using primefaces 5.1

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
});

function initialize()
{
    google.maps.event.addListener(PF('map').getMap(), 'zoom_changed', function () {
        var map = PF('map').getMap();

        var center = map.getCenter();
        var zoom = map.getZoom();

        myRemoteBoundsChange([{name: 'zoom', value: zoom}, {name: 'center', value: center}]);
     });
 }
```

```html
<body>
    <p:remoteCommand name="myRemoteBoundsChange" 
        actionListener="#{MB.drawPolygon}" update="map"/>

    <div id="divmap">
        <p:gmap id="map" model="#{MB.mapa}" center="#{MB.centroMapa}" zoom="#{MB.zoom}" 
                fitBounds="false" type="ROADMAP" widgetVar="map" />
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your remoteCommand to:

```
<p:remoteCommand name="myRemoteBoundsChange" actionListener="#{MB.drawPolygon}" 
    update="map" oncomplete="initialize()"/>
```

to add it again after the remote command is executed and the update has run
And change `<body>` to `<h:body>`

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your answer.
In fact I had tried this approach and it not worked. By the way.. I decided to drawn my polygons via client side.